# BigQuery SQL: Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRING

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery. I have a table with a column that has arrays like:

```
["632f","1cb080"]
["ca001"]
```

So a toy table might be:

```
id   fruits
1    ["632f","1cb080"]
2    ["ca001"]
```

I want:

```
id   fruits
1    632f
1    1cb080
2    ca001
```

The following works for me:

```
 WITH data AS (
   SELECT ["632f","1cb080"] AS fruits
 )
 SELECT fruits
 FROM data, UNNEST(fruits) AS fruits
```

And this case too:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT ["ca001"] AS fruits
)
SELECT fruits
FROM data, UNNEST(fruits) AS fruits
```

This case, with an empty string also works:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT [""] AS fruits
)
SELECT fruits
FROM data, UNNEST(fruits) AS fruits
```

But when I try to copy the above pattern, i.e. apply the above code using my actual data, I get the error:

`Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRING at [33:19]`

Why might this be? Are there some things I can check to debug this? As far as I can tell, my data only takes on forms like this:

```
id   fruits
1    ["632f","1cb080"]
2    ["ca001"]
```

Comment: BigQuery is not MySQL. Please don't spam unrelated tags. In particular, MySQL doesn't have `UNNEST`, so MySQL experience doesn't help with this.

Comment: check your code. most likely you have `UNNEST('fruits')` instead of `UNNEST(fruits)` - this is the only option that would produce that error message!

Comment: Can you simply perform `SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(fruits, '-') FROM data` to see if all the records of the column are an array of strings?

Comment: Hi @user2205916, Did the above comments help you?

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement below query will give the expected output.

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT 1 as id, ["632f","1cb080"] AS fruits
union all
SELECT 2 as id,["ca001"] AS fruits)

SELECT id,fruits1
FROM data, UNNEST(fruits) AS fruits1
```

As @Mikhail Berlyant, mentioned in the comment, if you use the query as:

```
SELECT id,fruits1
FROM data, UNNEST('fruits') AS fruits1
```

You will encounter the error message `Values referenced in UNNEST must be arrays. UNNEST contains expression of type STRING at [33:19]`.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.